# Android studio constantly complains about missing dependencies (highlights red). Unit tests also fail

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ide, dependencies

I'm becoming infuriated with Android Studio seemingly being unable to resolve dependencies properly. I get various classes of errors but generally the sign something is wrong is import statements being highlighted red, e.g.

[image]

[image]

Often this is innocuous and just affects code completion and symbol navigation. The app will build and run fine. However, for unit tests this really seems to present a problem as they won't run. For example, I'm currently seeing

```
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:1120)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.findAllMethodsInHierarchy(ReflectionUtils.java:1061)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:1045)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:1031)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.descriptor.VintageTestDescriptor.toMethodSource(VintageTestDescriptor.java:154)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.descriptor.VintageTestDescriptor.toTestSource(VintageTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.descriptor.VintageTestDescriptor.<init>(VintageTestDescriptor.java:54)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.TestClassRequestResolver.addChildrenRecursively(TestClassRequestResolver.java:110)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.TestClassRequestResolver.createCompleteRunnerTestDescriptor(TestClassRequestResolver.java:93)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.TestClassRequestResolver.determineRunnerTestDescriptor(TestClassRequestResolver.java:64)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.TestClassRequestResolver.createRunnerTestDescriptor(TestClassRequestResolver.java:59)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.lambda$discover$0(VintageDiscoverer.java:53)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.discover(VintageDiscoverer.java:55)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:61)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:82)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:48)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 43 more
```

There seems to be no consistent behaviour here. The packages which don't import vary.

Note that my colleagues can run tests and compile and the project runs in CI so I'm pretty sure the project is well defined.

I don't have a good way to solve the problem. I've tried combinations and permutations of all of the following

- UPDATED: Gradle sync
- Invalidate caches
- Cleaned project
- Closed project
- Manually delete files in project (including removing all non-essential IDE files)
- Deleted `$SOURCE/.gradle`
- Deleted `~/.gradle`

Nothing seems to work (consistently). I've currently no idea how to diagnose the problem without spending a lot of time digging into the workings of Android Studio and gradle.

Does anyone have insight or a clean solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried using `Gradle Sync`? It's a button in the toolbar.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, should have added that to the list. Will update

Comment: FYI I've taken a sledgehammer approach and uninstall Android studio and deleted everything. If that doesn't work then I give up!

Comment: can post your `build.gradle` files? Check the configurations inside

Comment: Not straightforward I'm afraid. Lot's of private info in there. I will come back to you